# Width of overflowing span inside div, IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I need to find out if the contents of a `span` is overflowing its parent `div`. It works fine in Chrome and FF, but not in IE9. I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Dynamic text content, which may or may not overflow the parent</span>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

In "real" browsers (i.e. not IE), it is easy to check if the span is wider than the div:

```
var innerSpan = $('.wrapper span');
var wrapperDiv = innerSpan.parent();
if (innerSpan.width() > wrapperDiv.width()) {
    // Overflow has happened
}
```

But in IE9, the call to `innerSpan.width()` only returns the visible size, which is of course always smaller that the wrapper's size. How can I detect if the text has overflown in IE9?

*NOTE: It only needs to work for IE9, not IE8, IE7 or any other version.*

**EDIT**
I found a solution, which detects overflow but requires the span to have `display: block;`. See my answer below.

Comment: What about `outerWidth()` instead of just `width()`?

Comment: offsetWidth and offsetHeight

Comment: @RGraham outerWidth has the same issue - it only returns the visible length.

Comment: @ArunAravind And offsetWidth as well, scrollWidth also for that matter.

Comment: I'm not sure that I got your requirement, but check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531135(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Emma The pixelWidth always return 0 in my case, perhaps because I don't have a declared width as part of the span's <code>style</code>?

Comment: I guess there is some syntax error var innerSpan = $.('.wrapper span');  should be var innerSpan = $('.wrapper span'); there is "dot(.)" between $ and (

Comment: @PravinVaichal : My bad, it's fixed now :) Unfortunately that error is not in the "real" code, so it doesn't fix the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I forced the span itself to be block-level, and set the overflow and text-overflow attributes on it. Then I could use scrollWidth and offsetWidth. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="inner">Dynamic text content, which may or may not overflow the parent</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}

.inner {
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And finally, the Javascript:

```
var innerSpan = $('.inner');
if (innerSpan[0].scrollWidth > innerSpan[0].offsetWidth) {
    console.log("Overflow!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The height of your span is `18px` as the height of text.When  the text overflows the `.wrapper` div automatically the heigth of span increases.

```
    var height=$('.wrapper span').css("height").replace('px','');
    console.log(height);
    if(parseFloat(height) > 18){
        console.log("overflow occured");
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/BuX93/)

Comment: This seems to work... haven't managed to get it working with elipsis cutoff yet, but maybe that will come.

Comment: I've updated the CSS of the question a bit, to show what I mean with the cutoff

Comment: @MW. See this updated fiddle according new updates http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/BuX93/1/

Comment: here u can directly go with width

Comment: Thanks for putting so much time into this :) The last fiddle works in Firefox (and probably Chrome), but on IE9 it reports the span width to 59 rather than 400-something, i.e. it just returns the visible width of the span.

Answer (score 0):

The element must be present in the DOM in order for the width to be calculated. If you need to calculate this before the user can see the element, try hiding it before putting it into the DOM.

Code Modified:

```
var innerSpan = $('.wrapper span');
var wrapperDiv = innerSpan.parent();
innerSpan.hide();
alert(innerSpan.width());
alert(wrapperDiv.width());
if (innerSpan.width() > wrapperDiv.width()) {
 // Overflow has happened
}
innerSpan.show();
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dWzeQ/2/

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The element is actually already present in the DOM. The issue is finding a way to get the width of a span in IE9 even though part of the span is hidden (because the parent div has overflow: hidden and whitespace: nowrap)